# Can multiple users run Firefox from a shared folder on the network?

Tags: firefox

Profiles would be stored in each individual machine.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. The profiles (including extensions) are stored in either the home directory or in appdata.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not.

I can run the same installation of Firefox twice on my machine with different profiles.

On my machine I have to run the second profile with the `-no-remote` switch. I don't think that will be applicable on multiple machines though.